# Any gotchas using static inner classes in a multi threaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, inner-classes

This is my first foray into multi threaded land and I'm currently implementing a solution using the Java concurrency library.  The code essentially takes in a number of service requests, submits all the requests asynchronously and returns a map of responses when all services have completed.  My code looks something like this:

```
public OuterClass {

  public IResponseMap sendAsynchronousRequests(IRequest... dataList) {
    List<RepositoryFutureTask<IRequest>> futures = new ArrayList<RepositoryFutureTask<IRequest>>();

    //create one future for each request in the list
    for (final IRequest request : dataList) {
        RepositoryFutureTask<IRequest> future = new RepositoryFutureTask<IRequest>(request.getId(), new Callable<IRequest>() {
            public IResponse call() {
                return request.getService().callService(request.getRequestData());
            }
        });
        futures.add(future);
    }

   //Submit each future for execution
   for(Future future:futures) {
      //Singleton ReqeustExecutorService maintains a pool of threads via
      // java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
      RequestExecutorService.execute(future);
   }

   //Block processing until all requests have finished and add responses to map
   //based on id as they finish
   IResponseMap responseMap = new ResponseMap();
   for(RepositoryFutureTask future:futures) {
      responseMap.put(future.getId(), future.get());
   }


    return responseMap;
  }

static class RepositoryFutureTask extends FutureTask<IResponse> {
     private String id;

    public RepositoryFutureTask(String theId, Callable<IResponse> callable) {
        super(callable);
          id = theId;
    }
    //standard getter for id omitted for conciseness
}
}
```

I'm primarily interested if my static inner class solution will create any issues in a multi threaded enviroment, but would also be interested in any other comments on the above solution.  Note that there's a chance the code above isn't perfect as its still somewhat pseudo code and I've generified it a lot.  Error handling has also been removed.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `RepositoryFutureTask` isn't an inner class. Inner classes look like this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Comment: @thejh - Apologies, my code above lacked the outer class definition.  Now added (though formatting is STILL off, grr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, static inner classes are loaded in a manner equivalent to a top level classes. See 8.5.2 of the JLS -- http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `synchronized` static method in a static nested class, it will be a lock on a different object to the same in the outer class. I would really recommend the `synchronized` modifier on any method, and particularly on a static method.

More a problem with anonymous inner classes, locks on `this` will be different. Even if you write `synchronized (this) {` it really isn't that obvious. I have seen it done a few times.

Theoretically I guess you could potentially run into trouble if the nested class static initialiser ran in parallel to the outer nester class static initialiser. Technically this is the same as running static intiailsers in two outer classes, but you are more likely to have cyclic dependencies with nested classes.

Answer (score 1):

No issues with using static inner class. The only issues is that `private String id;` is not `final`. Make it `final` and you'll be alright with thread-safety ;-)